# How to put my search function availaible in all pages?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this code in my views.py

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = "blog/blog_list.html"
    paginate_by = 5
    queryset = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_on')

    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
        context = super(BlogListView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        #filters = Blog.objects.order_by('-created_on')
        #context["filters"] = filters
        #context ['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
    def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
        qs = super(BlogListView,self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            qs=self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)
                )
        return qs
```

and in my template blog/base.html

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="GET" role="search">
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q"/>
      </div>
</form>
```

It only works in one blog_list.html page! How can I access my search feature in all template pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the blog list view knows how to process your search request, so you need to tell the form to send the request to that url. You do this by adding an `action` attribute to the form. For example, if your blog list view is available at `/blog/`, then you would do:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="GET" action="/blog/" role="search">
```

If you have named the blog list url pattern, then you can use the `{% url %}` tag, to avoid hardcoding the url. For example, if the name of the blog list url pattern was `blog_list`, you would do:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="GET" action="{% url 'blog_list' %}" role="search">
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked ! Silly question but newbie to django!!